# Java regex to match (group of words) subclass of (group of words)

Tags: java, regex

I would like to write a regular expression in Java to match a sequence of word characters and spaces followed by the sequence of characters "subclass of" a sequence of word characters and spaces:

Example strings which should be matched:

```
a subclass of b

a and b subclass of c

a and b subclass of c and d
```

The following strings should not be matched:

```
subclass of

a subclass of

subclass of b

a subclass of b subclass of c
```

I tried the following regex:

```
    [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+subclass of[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+

(?:(?!subclass of).)+subclass of(?:(?!subclass of).)+
```

but they both fall short of what I need.

Comment: Good Thinking. You should sure write it. But what should we do? Do you have any problem with that?

Comment: Could you tell us more about "general rule" of your regex? It may also help you write it all by yourself :)

Comment: let me edit the question to explain better what I want.

Comment: This is a good reference: [Pattern (Java)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Once you build your pattern from it, you can just do `"string".matches("pattern")` (substitute with variable/s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\\w+(?:\\s+and\\s+\\w+)?\\s+subclass\\s+of\\s+\\w+(?:\\s+and\\s+\\w+)?$
```

Here is the [Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/rJOe71yMdL):

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a little bit modification of your regex @anubhava:

`^\w+(?:\sand\s\w+)*\ssubclass\sof\s\w+(?:\sand\s\w+)*$`

To make sure that the group of (and \w+) can be matched more than once.

Live demo: [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/FjXtDO0upk)

Comment: Btw if you want to backreference the optional classes, you would add a \s? at the end of the second group.